# Zeroes in Report Response Data

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm query data from the Google Analytics API using java for last one week. However the response are coming back as zeros.

I'm using the following parameters for sending the request:

> Dimensions: ga:campaign
>   Metrics: ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue
>   Filter: ga:source==Bing;ga:medium==CPC;

But when I'm sending

> Filter: ga:source==google;ga:medium==cpc;

in the request there is response with data.

Comment: Can you please include your code we must be able to test it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried sending ga:source==bing;ga:medium==cpc  ? I believe the filter requests are case sensitive.

Comment: Before messing with the API, look at the Medium report and verify bing / cpc data exists.  Someone may have mislabled the campaign parameters, i.e. the traffic might show up as bing / ppc or bing.com / cpc